# LTSpice buck converter output voltage too high

Tags: power-electronics, ltspice, buck

I am designing a 311V to 48V buck converter in LTSpice using ideal components for now.

[image: schematic]

I am using a 48V/311V = 15.434% duty cycle in V2 which controls S1:

[image: V2 setup]

This is the simulation output:

[image: simulation]

Below is the inductor current and downstream switch voltage at steady-state:

[image]

I don't understand why the output voltage is ~52.1V instead of 48V. I tried different SPICE directives for the switch from various tutorials online but I get the same result. I also tried decreasing the max time step to 1u, to no avail.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Are you certain your calculations are correct? What does the inductor current look like?

Comment: Your calculations look correct, and with such a large inductor you will be in CCM mode where your equation applies.  Post a picture of the switch node and inductor current in steady-state and we may get some clues from there.

Comment: One issue, though I think it would cause lower rather than higher output, is that inductors in LTSpice default to nonzero resistance. Setting the inductor resistance to 0 explicitly might be worth trying.

Comment: Setting the inductor resistance to 0 didn't work :( I added a picture of the switch node and inductor current in steady state. The issue was solved by adding explicit rise and fall times for the pulsed voltage source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a rise time and fall time for the pulsed voltage source. There are default values used when you input 0 that are realistic but >0, if you want to see more ideal behavior use a value like 1n.

PULSE(0 5 10u 1n 1n 1.5434u 10u)

Comment: This worked, thank you!